# Apache 2.2 mod_proxy 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, apache2.2

How are you?

I've been trying to set up a proxy server using Apache 2.2 (in Debian 7 wheezy) and I'm not able to solve what is happening. I thought stackoverflow's family could help me :)

Okay, let's begin.

I will start by explaining my servers' distribution, and then I will explain what part it's not working as I would expect.

1. I've got a Linux Wheezy server in a Datacenter. This server have got a public IP in the eth0 interface.
2. Moreover, it has an extra network card. So in the eth1 there is connected an IPTV machine (Server2 in the image below) with its webadmin console (by going to the IP 192.168.4.40) to configure it.

The servers distribution looks like this:
[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B8F4.png)

So far, I've been using ssh tunneling to configure the IPTV machine: I create a ssh tunnel with the Linux Wheezy server and, once done, I put the webadmin console's IP (192.168.4.40) in my internet browser and I'm able to configure it.

I would like to use apache in order to access the webadmin console without the ssh tunnel. My goal is to access the IPTV Machine's (Server2 in the image above) webadmin console by using: http://server1publicIP/webadmin

To do that, I've looking on the internet how to set up a proxy using apache. Despite I've followed all forums' "how to do it" instructions it's not working :(

Details:

- Apache version in Linux Wheezy server: Apache 2.2.22
- Apache's modules enabled: proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http rewrite deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_html

File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyRequests Off

<Location /webadmin>
   ProxyPass http://192.168.4.40:80/
   ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.4.40:80/
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that it seems that I can see the login page but all requests are bad (404 Not Found error). Let me explain better by pasting what is seen in the network traffic analyzer:

```
            URL                                                 STATUS
[http://server1publicIP/webadmin]                        ->     200 OK
[http://server1publicIP/common/jquery-1.4.2.js] ->  404 Not Found
....
```

The problem is that it must request the following URL ("/webadmin" before "/common/"):

```
[http://server1publicIP/webadmin/common/jquery-1.4.2.js]
```

Instead of

```
[http://server1publicIP/common/jquery-1.4.2.js]
```

Do you know how to do that?

Please, if you need more information don't hesitate to ask me for it. I'm new in apache :(

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Hi! Not yet :( I'm still stuck on this and looking for a solution. If you could help me I would really appreciate it.... :)